# 'Open files based on content, not file extension' in IE 9

Tags: asp.net, mime-types, internet-explorer-9

I am supporting a site for a client on the intranet.  The site contains links to xml files.  These xml files have a unique extension and are intended to be opened by a specific application.  Using IE 8, we could support this by setting the option ‘Open files based on content, not file extension’ in Internet Options -> Security -> Custom Level.  In IE 9, this option has been removed.  Now these files open a new tab and display the xml.

Ideally, I’d like the file to just download through the download manager, but opening file in the application on the client machine would be acceptable as well.  What is the best way to do this in IE 9?  Is there a setting that I should adjust?  Server side, I have tried adjusting the MIME type, but it seems that if I sent it to something unknown (e.g. `application/octet-stream`) IE determines the content.  The last option I could think of would be to adjust the links such that they call an asp.net page that loads the contents of the xml into the response object but changes the header to contain `Content-Disposition:"attachment;filename=file.ext”`.

Any advice on the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

`Content-Disposition:attachment` is what you are looking for, yes. That is how you instruct browsers to download the file separately, and not try to display it.

You could use routing or rewriting to keep your file URLs, but have an ASHX handle the file so it can set that header. (don't use an ASPX; it's more than you need to just set some headers)

Answer (score 2):

I think the work around that I was looking for was the fact that the 'Open files based on content, not file extension' option in IE8 was renamed, 'Enable MIME Sniffing' in IE9.  But Andrew Barber's answer is the *correct* solution.